# automatic backup for access database

Tags: ms-access, vba

so I have made macro called autoexec to call on the function backup
here is the function:

```
Dim Source As String
Dim Target As String
Source = CurrentDb.Name
Target = CurrentProject.Path
Target = Target & Format(Date, "dd-mm") & "   "
Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb"
Call FileCopy(Source, Target, True)
```

however it always say there is which is invalid number of arguments or invalid property assignment
how can i fix this

Comment: which line is the debugger highlighting?

Comment: last line call filecopy line

Comment: Doesn't that have 2 arguments rather than the 3 you've given it? What is `TRUE` doing?

Comment: from microsoft it refers to overwrite

Comment: ok after i deleted the True part now it say run time error 70 permission denied

Comment: Is the source file open when you run this vba? if so, try closing and running again.

Comment: didnt work still run time error 70

Comment: You need to rethink https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/147394 Have a look at FileSystemObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now it say run time error 70 permission denied

It does so because you can't do this.

You can't copy the file from within itself.

Comment: yeah i have found this out now I'm trying to figure out how to fix it.any idea?